# accessing classes from another class in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two classes.

**GameData.h**

```
#import "TeamData.h"

@property (assign, nonatomic) GameData* teamA;
```

**TeamData.h**

```
@interface TeamData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* teamName;     
-(void) printTeamData;
```

A number of questions :

1. Inside GameData.m I have this code :

   TeamData* team = self.teamA;
   [team printTeamData];

The first line shows this warning :

```
Incompatible pointer types from TeamData* with an expression of type TeamData*
```

2. In another class, I am including GameData.h and I want to set the teamA name. How do I access that? So I want to fetch the teamA property from the GameData class and set its name property.

Comment: 1) your property teamA is of type GameData should be replaced to TeamData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GameData.h, your property points to its own class, not to `TeamData`

`@property (assign, nonatomic) GameData* teamA;`

`assign` is meant for primitive types such as BOOL or NSInteger.

The parent class should hold a `strong` reference to a child object.

So your property would be better off as

`@property (strong, nonatomic) TeamData* teamA;`

As for setting the teamA property, you would call `setTeamA:` on your `GameData` instance:

```
[myGameData setTeamA:...];
```

Comment: OMG I have this code in front of me for an hour, pasted it here, and never saw this typo. Damn auto-complete. How about the second one?