# Updating variables of another class objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ok following from [this earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361781/accessing-classes-from-another-class-in-objective-c) question and on the same design I have:

**GameData.h**

```
#import "TeamData.h"

@property (assign, nonatomic) TeamData* teamA;
```

**GameData.m**

```
-(void) printGameData
{

    NSLog(@"--------- Team---------- ");
    NSLog(@"%@",self.teamA);
    [self.teamA printTeamData];
...
}
```

**TeamData.h**

```
@interface TeamData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* teamName;     
-(void) printTeamData;
```

and on my View Controller I do have :

```
[[GameData sharedGameData].teamA setTeamName : self.teamA_name.text];
 NSLog(@"Before : %@ vs %@", [GameData sharedGameData].teamA.teamName,self.teamA_name.text);
  [[GameData sharedGameData] printGameData];
```

And the output is this :

```
 Before : (null) vs testname
--------- Team ---------- 
(null)
---------------------------
```

Why the teamA is always null? Do I need to alloc init it somewhere? if yes, where? I want whenever I retrieve it to retrieve the same instance.

***Edit 1:***

Change that to (strong,retain) didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initialising `TeamData` in the initialiser of `GameData`

in `GameData.h`

```
-(id) init;
```

in `GameData.m`

```
(id) init
{
  self = [super init];

  if (self)
  {
    self.teamA = [[TeamData alloc] init];
  }

  return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[GameData sharedGameData].teamA.teamName
```

Add this on the line before:

```
NSLog(@"%s sharedGameData: %@ teamA: %@ teamAName: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [GameData sharedGameData], [GameData sharedGameData].teamA, [GameData sharedGameData].teamA.teamName);
```

One or all of those `%@`s will spew a (null) and therein lies your problem;  you aren't initializing the data!

---

`teamA` is not initialized.  Initialize it.